# r2dbc connection closed exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, r2dbc

Please help me understand and resolve why I am getting and error when I try to fetch first of many records that can be fetched by a SELECT SQL statement using r2dbc on mssqlserver db.

**My gradle dependencies:**

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-client'
    implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-boot-starter:3.0.0'
    implementation 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-r2dbc'
    implementation 'io.r2dbc:r2dbc-mssql'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
}
```

**My code(sensitive content masked with xxxx):** [please understand that this is not production ready code and part of a POC in very rudimentary stage. so, most code is not confirming to production ready standard. so, please bear with that aspect.]

```
@Configuration
@EnableR2dbcRepositories(basePackages="com.xxxx.admin.db.repo")
public class DatabaseConfiguration extends AbstractR2dbcConfiguration
{
    
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    @Override
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        return new MssqlConnectionFactory(MssqlConnectionConfiguration.builder().host("xxxxxx")
                .database("xxxx").username(env.getProperty("xxxxx")).password(env.getProperty("xxxxxx")).build());
    }

}


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/admin")
public class AdminController  {
    @GetMapping("/junk")
    public Mono<Map<String, Object>> getUser() {
        return tmoUserRepo.getUser("XXXXXXXXXXX");      
    }
}


@Repository
public class TmoUserRepo {
    
private static final String GET_USER_SQL = "SELECT xxxxxxx WHERE ID=:userId ORDER BY XXX DESC, YYY ASC, ZZZ ASC;" ; 

    @Autowired
    private DatabaseClient dbClient;
    public Mono<Map<String, Object>> getUser(String userId) {
        dbClient.execute(GET_USER_SQL).bind("userId",userId).fetch().first().subscribe(System.out::println);
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Scenario-1.** This gives error (dbClient is an instance of DatabaseClient):

```
dbClient.execute(GET_USER_SQL).bind("userId",userId).fetch().first().subscribe(System.out::println);
```

**Scenario-2.** This goes through successfully:

```
dbClient.execute(GET_USER_SQL).bind("userId",userId).fetch().first().all(System.out::println);
```

=========================

**Scenario-1 what happens:** the following is printed TWICE in the log:

```
2020-12-04 18:37:38.569 DEBUG 18636 --- [actor-tcp-nio-1] o.s.d.r2dbc.core.DefaultDatabaseClient   : Executing SQL statement [SELECT usr.name_first AS namefirst,    
    usr.name_last AS namelast,
<<.... rest of SQL...>>
```

**The error message:**

```
2020-12-04 18:37:40.278 ERROR 18636 --- [actor-tcp-nio-1] reactor.core.publisher.Operators         : Operator called default onErrorDropped

io.r2dbc.mssql.client.ReactorNettyClient$MssqlConnectionClosedException: Connection closed
    at io.r2dbc.mssql.client.ReactorNettyClient.lambda$static$1(ReactorNettyClient.java:93) ~[r2dbc-mssql-0.8.5.RELEASE.jar:0.8.5.RELEASE]
    at io.r2dbc.mssql.client.ReactorNettyClient.drainError(ReactorNettyClient.java:629) ~[r2dbc-mssql-0.8.5.RELEASE.jar:0.8.5.RELEASE]
    at io.r2dbc.mssql.client.ReactorNettyClient.handleClose(ReactorNettyClient.java:614) ~[r2dbc-mssql-0.8.5.RELEASE.jar:0.8.5.RELEASE]
    at io.r2dbc.mssql.client.ReactorNettyClient.access$600(ReactorNettyClient.java:85) ~[r2dbc-mssql-0.8.5.RELEASE.jar:0.8.5.RELEASE]
    at io.r2dbc.mssql.client.ReactorNettyClient$2.onComplete(ReactorNettyClient.java:289) ~[r2dbc-mssql-0.8.5.RELEASE.jar:0.8.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onComplete(Operators.java:2016) ~[reactor-core-3.3.11.RELEASE.jar:3.3.11.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeek.java:252) ~[reactor-core-3.3.11.RELEASE.jar:3.3.11.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.terminateReceiver(FluxReceive.java:441) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.13.RELEASE.jar:0.9.13.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.drainReceiver(FluxReceive.java:238) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.13.RELEASE.jar:0.9.13.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundNext(FluxReceive.java:362) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.13.RELEASE.jar:0.9.13.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundNext(ChannelOperations.java:358) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.13.RELEASE.jar:0.9.13.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:96) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.13.RELEASE.jar:0.9.13.RELEASE]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:93) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
    at io.r2dbc.mssql.client.ssl.TdsSslHandler.channelRead(TdsSslHandler.java:380) ~[r2dbc-mssql-0.8.5.RELEASE.jar:0.8.5.RELEASE]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[netty-common-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]

2020-12-04 18:37:40.280 ERROR 18636 --- [actor-tcp-nio-1] r.n.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler     : [id: 0x2fb997cb, L:/10.100.26.236:55810 ! R:tmidevsql12/10.211.0.250:1433] Error was received while reading the incoming data. The connection will be closed.

reactor.core.Exceptions$BubblingException: io.r2dbc.mssql.client.ReactorNettyClient$MssqlConnectionClosedException: Connection closed
    at reactor.core.Exceptions.bubble(Exceptions.java:173) ~[reactor-core-3.3.11.RELEASE.jar:3.3.11.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.onErrorDropped(Operators.java:635) ~[reactor-core-3.3.11.RELEASE.jar:3.3.11.RELEASE]
    at io.r2dbc.mssql.util.FluxDiscardOnCancel$FluxDiscardOnCancelSubscriber.onError(FluxDiscardOnCancel.java:95) ~[r2dbc-mssql-0.8.5.RELEASE.jar:0.8.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:214) ~[reactor-core-3.3.11.RELEASE.jar:3.3.11.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:214) ~[reactor-core-3.3.11.RELEASE.jar:3.3.11.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onError(FluxFilter.java:151) ~[reactor-core-3.3.11.RELEASE.jar:3.3.11.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandle$HandleConditionalSubscriber.onError(FluxHandle.java:406) ~[reactor-core-3.3.11.RELEASE.jar:3.3.11.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.EmitterProcessor.checkTerminated(EmitterProcessor.java:489) ~[reactor-core-3.3.11.RELEASE.jar:3.3.11.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.EmitterProcessor.drain(EmitterProcessor.java:356) ~[reactor-core-3.3.11.RELEASE.jar:3.3.11.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.EmitterProcessor.onError(EmitterProcessor.java:286) ~[reactor-core-3.3.11.RELEASE.jar:3.3.11.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:214) ~[reactor-core-3.3.11.RELEASE.jar:3.3.11.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:214) ~[reactor-core-3.3.11.RELEASE.jar:3.3.11.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:214) ~[reactor-core-3.3.11.RELEASE.jar:3.3.11.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandle$HandleSubscriber.onError(FluxHandle.java:196) ~[reactor-core-3.3.11.RELEASE.jar:3.3.11.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyInner.onError(MonoFlatMapMany.java:247) ~[reactor-core-3.3.11.RELEASE.jar:3.3.11.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:214) ~[reactor-core-3.3.11.RELEASE.jar:3.3.11.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.EmitterProcessor.checkTerminated(EmitterProcessor.java:489) ~[reactor-core-3.3.11.RELEASE.jar:3.3.11.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.EmitterProcessor.drain(EmitterProcessor.java:356) ~[reactor-core-3.3.11.RELEASE.jar:3.3.11.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.EmitterProcessor.onError(EmitterProcessor.java:286) ~[reactor-core-3.3.11.RELEASE.jar:3.3.11.RELEASE]
    at io.r2dbc.mssql.client.ReactorNettyClient.drainError(ReactorNettyClient.java:629) ~[r2dbc-mssql-0.8.5.RELEASE.jar:0.8.5.RELEASE]
    at io.r2dbc.mssql.client.ReactorNettyClient.handleClose(ReactorNettyClient.java:614) ~[r2dbc-mssql-0.8.5.RELEASE.jar:0.8.5.RELEASE]
    at io.r2dbc.mssql.client.ReactorNettyClient.access$600(ReactorNettyClient.java:85) ~[r2dbc-mssql-0.8.5.RELEASE.jar:0.8.5.RELEASE]
    at io.r2dbc.mssql.client.ReactorNettyClient$2.onComplete(ReactorNettyClient.java:289) ~[r2dbc-mssql-0.8.5.RELEASE.jar:0.8.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onComplete(Operators.java:2016) ~[reactor-core-3.3.11.RELEASE.jar:3.3.11.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeek.java:252) ~[reactor-core-3.3.11.RELEASE.jar:3.3.11.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.terminateReceiver(FluxReceive.java:441) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.13.RELEASE.jar:0.9.13.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.drainReceiver(FluxReceive.java:238) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.13.RELEASE.jar:0.9.13.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundNext(FluxReceive.java:362) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.13.RELEASE.jar:0.9.13.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundNext(ChannelOperations.java:358) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.13.RELEASE.jar:0.9.13.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:96) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.13.RELEASE.jar:0.9.13.RELEASE]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:93) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
    at io.r2dbc.mssql.client.ssl.TdsSslHandler.channelRead(TdsSslHandler.java:380) ~[r2dbc-mssql-0.8.5.RELEASE.jar:0.8.5.RELEASE]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[netty-common-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: io.r2dbc.mssql.client.ReactorNettyClient$MssqlConnectionClosedException: Connection closed
    at io.r2dbc.mssql.client.ReactorNettyClient.lambda$static$1(ReactorNettyClient.java:93) ~[r2dbc-mssql-0.8.5.RELEASE.jar:0.8.5.RELEASE]
    ... 32 common frames omitted

2020-12-04 18:37:40.280  WARN 18636 --- [actor-tcp-nio-1] reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive        : [id: 0x2fb997cb, L:/10.100.26.236:55810 ! R:tmidevsql12/10.211.0.250:1433] An exception has been observed post termination, use DEBUG level to see the full stack: reactor.core.Exceptions$BubblingException: io.r2dbc.mssql.client.ReactorNettyClient$MssqlConnectionClosedException: Connection closed
```

Comment: impossible to answer when you have provided a single row of code without any context. Post more of the code and how you are calling the function.

Comment: I updated question with some additional code that establishes context. Pl help in resolving the blocker.

Comment: Most of the code that you have their is not necessary since you are using r2dbc repository. Please have look at https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/r2dbc/docs/1.1.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#reference. That should help.

Answer (score 3):

### Short answer

Your problem is probably here:

```
dbClient.execute(GET_USER_SQL).bind("userId",userId).fetch().first().subscribe(System.out::println);
return null;
```

You probably need to change this to:

```
return dbClient.execute(GET_USER_SQL)
               .bind("userId",userId)
               .fetch()
               .first();
```

### Long answer

Doing reactive programming is a lot different than regular Java programming, and if you try to do regular Java you will have a hard time.

First of all, `null` values are not allowed in reactive programming, so never return `null`.

Reactive programming works with *producers* and *consumers*. Your application is a *producer* and the calling client (web app, mobile app, postman, curl etc) is the *consumer*. It usually is the one that initiated the call that is the *consumer*. The consumer starts by *subscribing* to the producer, so the client subscribes to the server.

When this happens, the server will start from the end of your code, and traverse up until it finds what is producing the values (your database). And during this it will assemble a sort of *callback chain*. This part is called the *Assembly phase*. When this phase is done, your application will pump out ONE (if its a `Mono`) or Many (if its a `Flux`) values.

So *nothing will happen until someone subscribes*.

```
// Only a declaration, nothing happens
Mono.just("Foobar");
```

While:

```
// Someone subscribes, chain is built and value is produced
Mono.just("Foobar").subscribe(s -> System.out.println(s));
```

This also works with functions:

```
public Mono<String> getFoobar() {
    return Mono.just("Foobar");
}

getFoobar().subscribe(s -> System.out.println(s));
```

But what if you don't want to return anything:

```
public Mono<Void> getFoobar() {
    return Mono.just("Foobar").then(); 
    // then will throw away whatever is returned from the previous and instead return a Mono<Void> that will signal to the next part in the chain that it is done.
}

getFoobar().subscribe();
```

Or you can return a `Mono.empty()` which will translate into a `Mono<Void>`

```
public Mono<Void> getFoobar() {
    return Mono.just("Foobar").flatMap(s -> {
        // Return an empty, which will translate to a Mono<Void>
        return Mono.empty();
    });
}

getFoobar().subscribe();
```

So if we look at your two scenarios:

```
dbClient.execute(GET_USER_SQL)
        .bind("userId",userId)
        .fetch()
        .first()
        .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Here *YOU* are subscribing, so it works, but then the calling client wants to subscribe and it breaks.

```
dbClient.execute(GET_USER_SQL)
        .bind("userId",userId)
        .fetch()
        .first()
        .all(System.out::println);
```

This works, but depending on if you return or not, the value will get sent to the calling client. the `all` needs to be removed so you can return the value produced from `first` all the way out to the client.

I have tried to explain this the best I can, all this can be read about in the excellent [Reactor Documentation](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/)

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Removal of "return null" and changing to the following did not eliminate error:

public Mono<Map<String, Object>> getUser(String userId) {
   return dbClient.execute(GET_USER_SQL).bind("userId",userId).fetch().first();
}



However, replacing first() with all() and replacing Mono with Flux in return type did not produce error.

Question of why first() method causes exception is still open and un-answered.

Answer (score 1):

```bash
Failed to obtain R2DBC Connection; nested exception is dev.miku.r2dbc.mysql.client.MySqlConnectionClosedException: Cannot exchange messages because the connection is closed
```

I faced this problem. after adding the `r2dbc-pool` library, the problem got away.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.r2dbc</groupId>
   <artifactId>r2dbc-pool</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very simple.

### you should have created the database manually before running the project.

because spring tries to make the connection with the name of the database that you mentioned. create the database and run the project. the error will be gone for most cases.